# Does Anaconda have any libraries for PCL for C++ for using in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, point-cloud-library

I am currently looking for best method to install pcl libraries in my windows system. I dont know if anaconda offers any pcl libraries for c++?

Comment: From a brief google search, it seems like it does offer, even though I don't know Anaconda enough to really tell about the platform/tool or the quality of these packages: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pcl, https://anaconda.org/ccordoba12/pcl. In any case, installation instructions here, if it'd help: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/

Comment: @FlávioLisbôa Thanks for the info. Actually i looked into this earlier but i dont know clearly if it is offering support for c++. I can use it for python for sure but due to some timing constraints, i am thinking to do it in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCL offers prebuilt binaries for windows (AllInOne installer) at [releases](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/releases). Latest binaries: 1.10.1

Since your question stated "best method to install pcl libraries in my windows system", I think it's worth mentioning this non-anaconda option.

Comment: Thanks :-). I just found all in one installer but i did with vcpkg with one person help!

Comment: Ok, so add it as an answer, so that future users will see all available alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/) [PCL package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pcl) does offer C++ support for PCL v1.9.1, but be mindful that it does not build all PCL components. The build script used to create the package can be found [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/pcl-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/bld.bat) if you'd like to know more about what is or is not enabled.